# DevExpress GridView print with my text

Tags: c#, devexpress

When I click on the "print" I have shown a window for printing, in which the data from my DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView;

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridView.ShowPrintPreview();
}
I want this data to add your text.how it can be implemented?

https://pp.vk.me/c620629/v620629208/926a/GbIsa-3vQKk.jpg


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    somemethod();
    gridView.ShowPrintPreview();
}

void somemethod()
{
    DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink pl = new DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink();
    printingSystem1 = new PrintingSystem();
    printingSystem1.Links.Add(pl);

    pl.Component = _gridControl;

    pl.CreateReportHeaderArea += new CreateAreaEventHandler(pl_CreateReportHeaderArea);
}

void pl_CreateReportHeaderArea(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
{
    TextBrick brick1 = e.Graph.DrawString("Your text goes here", Color.Black,
    new RectangleF(0, 0, 620, 20), DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None);
    brick1.HorzAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;
    brick1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Comment: Please take time to word your question. What does "I want this data to add your text" mean?

Comment: Look at the picture on the link I want

Comment: Please, add some effort to format text and question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) 
{ 
  PrintableComponentLink pl = new PrintableComponentLink(new PrintingSystem());
  pl.Component = gridControl1;
  pl.CreateAreaEventHandler+= new CreateAreaEventHandler(pl_CreateReportHeaderArea);
  pl.CreateDocument();
  pl.ShowPreview();
}

public void pl_CreateReportHeaderArea(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
{
        TextBrick brick1 = e.Graph.DrawString("Your text goes here", Color.Black,
           new RectangleF(0, 0, 620,20), DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None);
        brick1.HorzAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;
        brick1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a custom header to the xtragrid print preview you need to handle the CreateAreaEventHandler event of PrintableCompnentLink.

```
PrintingSystem printingSystem1;

void somemethod()
{
 DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink pl = new     DevExpress.XtraPrinting.PrintableComponentLink();
        printingSystem1.Links.Add(pl);

       pl.Component = _gridControl;

 pl.CreateAreaEventHandler+= new CreateAreaEventHandler(pl_CreateReportHeaderArea);
}

 void pl_CreateReportHeaderArea(object sender, CreateAreaEventArgs e)
    {
            TextBrick brick1 = e.Graph.DrawString("Your text goes here", Color.Black,
               new RectangleF(0, 0, 620,20), DevExpress.XtraPrinting.BorderSide.None);
            brick1.HorzAlignment = HorzAlignment.Center;
            brick1.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 12, FontStyle.Bold);
  }
```

Comment: you need to link your grid control to the printable link